# Detecting ambulance siren using raspberry pi

Tags: python

am trying to find a way of detecting ambulance siren using a raspberry pi,I have tried using fast Fourier transform together with numpy in python to isolate ambulance siren but its not working. any one with an idea kindly assist

Comment: Questions that ask, "why isn't this working?" usually get more/better answers if you show people what _this_ is.

Comment: `but its not working. any one with an idea` - yes, you'll need to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, record the sound as the siren goes by. Use FFT to isolate what you **think** the frequencies are. Then filter out everything except those frequencies, and play your recording back again. If you hear the siren, your guess was correct.